# How do I update wine in one wineprefix?

Tags: 12.04, wine

Does anyone know how I can go about updating the version of wine that one prefix uses without self-destructing everything in it?

I want to bring it from 1.4 to 1.5.5 - I read on a forum that someone got the microphone working in Rosetta Stone with Ubuntu 12.04 and wine 1.5.5.

Thanks for any guidance on this matter.  :)

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11984993&postcount=20

Update:  Issue resolved.
Thanks to zuberuber I was able to approach the issue in a different light.  :)

I made a new prefix called "test" in PlayOnLinux.  I compared the new prefix with the Rosetta prefix.
It contained a PlayOnLinux.cfg file along with the reg files.
It contained:

```
ARCH=x86
VERSION=1.5.0
```

I copied this over to the Rosetta prefix and adjusted it:

```
ARCH=x86
VERSION=1.4.1
```

After doing that, I was able to change it from 1.4.1 to 1.5.0.  I confirmed it in the prefix's winecfg's About tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually You can't. Wineprefix is variable from wine, therefore You can't update wine within single wineprefix. However You can install multiple versions of wine on Your Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to clarify!  Now let's say I install wine 1.5.5 through PlayOnLinux;  How do I make sure the prefix uses it?  Or am I missing a concept here?  I do that.

Comment: I don't know about PlayOnLinux but when You install wine manually from source, You can just `/path/to/wine --wineprefix=foobar`